# Slow page render due to checkboxs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a .aspx webpage which requires upto 500ish records from the DB to be displayed along with a checkbox for each. I am having issues whereas the page takes up to 15 seconds to render.

I added a stopwatch to the pageload event, that finishes and response.writes it to the page after approx 4.7 seconds . I then have a further 10 second wait while the rest of the page (namely the checkboxs) are rendered.

Originally the checkboxs where a button and that has no noticeable extra rendering time after the pageload.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtScheduledVisits.Rows)
{
   ...
   results.Append("<tr>");
   results.Append("<td> <input type='checkbox'> </td>");
   results.Append("<td>" + fullname + "</td>");
   results.Append("</tr>");
   ...
}
lblResults.Text = results.ToString();
```

On my MainMaster page i have referenced:

```
<script src="js/icheck.js"></script> <!-- Custom Checkbox + Radio -->
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For your Requirement use SetTimeout

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtScheduledVisits.Rows)
{
   ...
   results.Append("<tr>");
   results.Append("<td> <input type='checkbox'> </td>");
   results.Append("<td>" + fullname + "</td>");
   results.Append("</tr>");
   ...
}



 setTimeout(function(){
lblResults.Text = results.ToString(); //Render your Views
    return false;
    }, 4700);
```

I hope this help

Comment: What would this actually do? stop the foreach loop if it ran for more then 4700?

Comment: This will call the function with  `return false;`  with 4.7 delay...were we render our view before timeout... that set to 4.7sec

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this volume of markup would take some time to render.

You might not be able to improve the *actual* rendering time much, but you could perhaps improve the *perceived* rendering time.

Personally I would render only about 50 checkboxes on the initial page load, then the rest either on DOMContentLoaded (when the initial HTML is rendered) or when the user clicks a Load More button.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in the past. The issue seems to be with large numbers of controls on a page (checkboxes, textboxes, drop down lists etc).

For pages where this is a problem I have stripped most / all controls out of the page load. When the user clicks on a row I then copy in a set of controls for the row from a template using jQuery.